# Bootstrap scrollspy doesn't works in ie?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, magento

I have implement bootstrap scrollspy in my magento site. It works well in FF and Chrome.

But It doesn't works in IE. Can any help to fix this issue.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'd need to actually provide a URL and some more information on what you've tried. Does it work on the demo site? If so, then you know it may be something with your implementation. Have you checke the console for JS errors?

Comment: It works in ie9 also. But it doesn't works in the ie earlier versions

Answer (score 0):

Have you include the html5.js in header? because ie8 requires html5.js files

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer